# Check div if empty and displaying the content of the div in another as a string

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hey I have this code and it is not working as I want it to do

```
function showcode() {
    if ($('#sampleeditor').text() != '') {//check if the div is not empty => not working
        var orgcontent = document.getElementById('sampleeditor').innerHTML;//get the content of the div
        var copiedcontent = document.getElementById('contentcode').innerHTML = orgcontent;//place the content in the target div || the issue here is that the content is shown as it is|| I want it to be a text of the code
    } else {
        document.getElementById('contentcode').innerHTML = "Nothing to show";//if the original div is empty show this text
    }
    $("#Showcode").modal('show');// the modal where the contentcode is placed.
}
```

basically I want the code to take the content of a div(sampleeditor) and display them in another div (contentcode) inside a modal(showcode) as a text.

This code is copying the content as it is. eg. if I have an image in the first div it is displayed as an image in the other .I want it to be like this `div class="divimage" id="WNI4022"><img src="empty.jpg" width="100px" height="100px"></div>`

Comment: Does the #sampleeditor div contain any text? Not HTML, text, because jQuery text() only retrieves text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you're looking for is not `innerHTML` -- this will just give you the content in the element ... replace that with `outerHTML` which will give you the actual **source code** of the element -- In this case for the `orgcontent` variable

---

I've noted where the issue is arising from

```js
function escapeHtml(text) {
  var map = {
    '&': '&amp;',
    '<': '&lt;',
    '>': '&gt;',
    '"': '&quot;',
    "'": '&#039;'
  };

  return text.replace(/[&<>"']/g, function(m) { return map[m]; });
}
// The above is a function to change the special characters so they can show up in the <code> tag

function showcode() {
    if ($('#sampleeditor').text() != '') {//check if the div is not empty => not working
        var orgcontent = document.getElementById('sampleeditor').outerHTML;//get the content of the div
        var copiedcontent = document.getElementById('contentcode').innerHTML = orgcontent;//place the content in the target div || the issue here is that the content is shown as it is|| I want it to be a text of the code
        document.getElementById('formatted-contentcode').innerHTML = escapeHtml(orgcontent);
        // The above formatted-contentcode will have the escaped characters
    } else {
        document.getElementById('contentcode').innerHTML = "Nothing to show";//if the original div is empty show this text
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  showcode();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="sampleeditor">This will be shown in the other div</div><br/>
<!-- If you want to put actual source code in a div, you have to wrap them in code tags
Then escape "<" as "&lt;" and ">" as "&gt;"
-->
<div id="contentcode">Another thing</div><br/>
<!--  Notice the difference  
The one below has been passed to the `escapeHtml()` function -->
<div id="formatted-contentcode">Another thing</div>
```

For you to put actual source code, they have to be in `<code>` tags and you have to escape the special characters ...  the `escapeHtml()` function does the job.

And another way is also putting the source code in a textarea or input element which will appear as the actual code.

Comment: still the same. The code is not displayed as lines of code but as actual content

Comment: View edited above ... The function that does all the job is the `escapeHtml()` function ... That should escape the special characters as expected